# Find and replace dollar sign

Tags: regex, vb.net

This not working for me:

```
            dim regex as Regex = New Regex("\b\$_GET\b")
            src = regex.Replace(src, "somthing")
```

It returns the original string.

I also got out of memory when try this in a long file:

```
            dim regex as Regex = New Regex("\$\b_GET\b")
            src = regex.Replace(src, "somthing")
```

Note: try to find and replace php variables like `$_GET`, `$foo` etc.

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: @Doorknob I want free waffles when my regex fail :(

Comment: what not working mean? return original string. I also added new stuff.

Comment: chating instead help!

Comment: @exim Would you mind to post an example string?

Comment: @reporter I am trying to replace a php file. use a php source code for example.

Comment: What is the file size? and how do you read file and apply Regex on it ? Please show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, before "$_GET" there is no [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`.

A word boundary matches on a change from a word character to a non-word character, or the other way round. I assume before "$_GET" there is either the start of the string or whitespace, for both positions (Between StartOfString and "$", Whitespace and "$") there is no word boundary.

Your second example should kind of work, since there is a word boundary between "$" and "_".

You can use the inverse anchor instead.

```
dim regex as Regex = New Regex("\B\$_GET\b")
```

`\B` would require a non-word character before the "$", since it is the negation of `\b`.

Comment: it works for $_GET but not for $foo for example. I am trying to replace php variables.

Comment: update: works for $foo etc. too but got out of memory for a long files

Answer (score 0):

A word boundary (`\b`) is not very useful near a dollar sign, just use:

```
dim regex as Regex = New Regex("\$_GET\b")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the [`word boundary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `\b` at the start of the regexp, the code must be:

```
dim regex as Regex = New Regex("\$_GET\b")
```